# Not able to select value from multi select drop down (Combo box) in Selenium C# webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am having div class and under that UL element and under that LI element and in that LI there are option values which I want to select. These are not having any id, cssselector, linktext or xpath.
How to select them?

Comment: like @Adelin said, you need to supply a code example of what you tried to do. Before that happens, we can't help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following answer for selecting the dynamic drop down.

```
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("language")).Click();   
            IList<IWebElement> cartItems = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".active-result"));
            string[] arr = new string[] { "Breton", "Catalan" };

            int i = 1;
            int j = 0;
            foreach (IWebElement cartItem in cartItems)
            {
                var value = cartItem.Text;
                if(value== arr[j])
                {
                    this.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ChildLanguages_chosen']/div/ul/li["+i+"]")).Click();
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
```